# How can I say... Would you like to go to Madonna's concert? or would you like to go to a Madonna's concert?

Tags: articles

How can I say... Would you like to go to Madonna's concert? or would you like to go to **a** Madonna's concert?

or I have tickets to Madonna's concert or I have tickets to **a** Madonna's concert?

Answer (score 1):

*A* is an indefinite article.

> Would you like to go to Madonna’s concert?

This sentence is talking about a specific concert.

The second one is grammatically incorrect.

You can say:

> Would you like to go to a concert by Madonna

This is saying would you like to go to a concert by Madonna not talking about a specific concert.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> Would you like to go to **a Madonna concert**?

"Madonna" acts as an adjective, and as such is not pluralized.